# Calculate $2^{2^{2006}} (mod3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Calculate $2^{2^{2006}} (mod3)$

Well, I believe it is not correct but can I say that:

$$2^{2^{2006}} (mod3) = 4^{2006} \equiv _3 1^{2006}(mod3) = 1$$

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: $4^{2006}=2^{2\cdot 2006}=2^{4012}\neq 2^{2^{2006}}$.

Comment: $2^{2^{2006}}\equiv (-1)^{2^{2006}}\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, because $2^{2006}$ is even.

Comment: What you $can$ say is that $2 \equiv -1 \mod 3$, which might simplify things.

Comment: $2^{2^{2006}}=2^{\left(2^{2006}\right)}\neq \left(2^2\right)^{2006}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By *Lil' Fermat*, $2^2\equiv 1\mod 3$. Hence $2^n\equiv 2^{n\bmod2}\mod 3$.

In particular $2^{2006}\equiv 0\mod 2$, so
$$2^{2^{2006}}\equiv 2^0=1\mod 3.$$

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem! Cool! :-) Nice application in this context! +1

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand that $2^{2^{2006}} \neq 4^{2006}$. This is easily verified as $4^{2006} = (2^2)^{2006}\neq 2^{2^{2006}}$. So your solution doesn't work, unfortunately.

But here's how to do it intuitively, using a little pattern-recognition skill.

Notice that:

1. $2^1 \equiv 2\ (\text{mod}\ 3)$
2. $2^2 \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 3)$
3. $2^3 \equiv 2\ (\text{mod}\ 3)$
4. $2^4 \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 3)$

I hope you can see the general pattern here:
$$
2^{2n} \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 3)
$$
and,
$$
2^{2n + 1} \equiv 2\ (\text{mod}\ 3)
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. That's just a fancy way of writing “$2$ raised to the power of something even will be $1$ mod $3$ and when raised to an odd power, it will be $2$ mod $3$”

Now, $2^{2006}$ is a very even number (make sure you understand why). Therefore, the answer to your question is:
$$
2^{2^{2006}}=2^{even}\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ 3)
$$

*PS:* You did manage to find the right answer, but your method was faulty. Hope my explanation cleared it up for you.

Comment: I like your answer except for the part where you referred to a convention for repeated exponentiation that students have to memorize as something that is "easily verified".

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ n\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\!-\!1\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#c00}{n\!-\!1})^{\large 2k}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 2k}\equiv 1\ $ by the [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Remark** $\ $ The proof you gave is inorrect because $\,\rm 2^{\large 2^{\Large N}}\!\!\neq (2^{\large 2})^{\large N},\,$ i.e. $\,2$^($2$^N)$\,\neq (2$^$2)$^N

Answer (score 3):

$2^n\equiv 2\pmod 3$ when $n$ is odd and $2^n\equiv 1\pmod 3$ when $n$ is even.

$2^{2006}$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $2^2 = 1$ mod $3$. Thus we are left with finding out what $r = 2^{2016}$ mod $2$ is and then we can write $2^{2^{2016}}$ as $2^{2k + r}$.

Comment: You sir are right.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction that $2^{2k}\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $2^{2k+1}\equiv 2\pmod 3$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So since $2^{2006}$ is even, then $2^{2^{2006}}\equiv 1\pmod 3$.